# Stacking dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a way to stack a dataframe in pandas in the following manner:

```
id     val
id01   ['a', 'b']
id02   ['b']
id03   []
id04   ['a','c']
```

to:

```
id01   'a'
       'b'
id02   'b'
id04   'a'
       'c'
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far so that we could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want `Series` with `MultiIndex` use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with `DataFrame` contructor:

```
s = pd.DataFrame(df['val'].values.tolist(), index=df['id']).stack()
print (s)
id     
id01  0    a
      1    b
id02  0    b
id04  0    a
      1    c
dtype: object
```

---

If need `DataFrame` add double [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) - first fore remove second level of `MultiIndex` and second for create column from index:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(df['val'].values.tolist(), index=df['id'])
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .reset_index(name='val'))
print (df)
     id val
0  id01   a
1  id01   b
2  id02   b
3  id04   a
4  id04   c
```

Last if need replace duplicated values use `loc` + [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df.loc[df['id'].duplicated(), 'id'] = ''
print (df)
     id val
0  id01   a
1         b
2  id02   b
3  id04   a
4         c
```

Answer (score 0):

For a Pandorable solution, [@jezrael's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49812577/9209546) is good.

If efficiency is a concern, building a new dataframe is often more efficient than `stack`:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['id01', 'id02', 'id03', 'id04'],
                   'val': [['a', 'b'], ['b'], [], ['a', 'c']]})

lens = list(map(len, df['val']))

res = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.repeat(df['id'].values, lens),
                    'val': list(chain.from_iterable(df['val']))})

print(res)

#      id val
# 0  id01   a
# 1  id01   b
# 2  id02   b
# 3  id04   a
# 4  id04   c
```

---

**Performance benchmarking**

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['id01', 'id02', 'id03', 'id04'],
                   'val': [['a', 'b'], ['b'], [], ['a', 'c']]})

df = pd.concat([df]*100000)

def jp(df):
    lens = list(map(len, df['val']))

    res = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.repeat(df['id'].values, lens),
                        'val': list(chain.from_iterable(df['val']))})

    return res

def jez(df):
    return (pd.DataFrame(df['val'].values.tolist(), index=df['id'])
              .stack()
              .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
              .reset_index(name='val'))

%timeit jp(df)   # 137 ms per loop
%timeit jez(df)  # 197 ms per loop
```

Comment: @jezrael, hmm I pasted my full benchmarking - am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @jezrael, yes I use windows

Comment: Interesting, with `%%timeit` get your answer is slowiest.

Comment: with your functions I get `In [319]: %timeit jp(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 106 ms per loop

In [320]: %timeit jez(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 125 ms per loop`

Comment: I see, so relatively it's roughly the same - just your machine is faster :) - But do you know why `%%timeit` different?

Comment: Can you test it with `%%timeit` ? If different timings like me

Comment: @jezrael, I've never used `%%timeit` :S - can you suggest how?

Comment: @jezrael Thks, give me some time pls - a bit busy but I want to find out what's happening.